# Spotify Web API Add new controllable device to Spotify devices list

Tags: api, spotify

I try to set up a new device which is able to use Spotiy functionality over Spotify Web API.

There is a API call https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-a-users-available-devices/ where I can get available devices.

The problem is now that there is no call to **add** a new device to this list. The new device is not my smart phone but an **external** spotify certified speaker.

Native Spotify application adds the external speaker in an unknown(?) way. 
I tried to capture some packages with Wireshark which are sent from 
speakers when using Spotify but I just see some MDNS broadcasts.

**Question:**
Is it possible to add the external device over Spotify Web API? Do someone know how Spotify Application implements this register process?

Comment: **August 2017** ; There's currently no way to do it, you can check out the related issues on their GitHub repository: [#540](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/540), [#538](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/538)

Comment: @Teh thanks for the links! However how the native Spotify App does this? If  I use the App before, the call to get available devices return the values for the external speaker.

Comment: There's no public API available for registering new devices. However there have been some attempts at reverse engineering the library: [1] [Reversing Spotify Connect protocol](http://divideoverflow.com/2014/08/reversing-spotify-connect/), [2] [Makes a device show up in spotify connect devices list, but nothing else yet](https://gist.github.com/Fornoth/562a2db691051c381a8f), [3] [plietar/librespot](https://github.com/plietar/librespot/blob/master/src/discovery.rs#L56), [4] [sashahilton00/spotify-connect-resources](https://github.com/sashahilton00/spotify-connect-resources)